# Click to change grid cells colors

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to make an interactive grid but the colors won't change when I click on the squares. The grid has to be multicolored and when one clicks on the grid, the boxes inside of it should change color to a random color of five colors. The grid isn't changing colors however, and I'm not sure how to make each object carry its own color.

I have a square class that constructs an object to be a rectangle

```
public class square extends JPanel {

    private int sizeOfSquare = 10;
    private Color theColor;
    private int theXindexcode;
    private int theYindexcode;

    public void constructSquare (Graphics g){

            g.setColor(theColor);
            g.drawRect(theXindexcode, theYindexcode, sizeOfSquare, sizeOfSquare);
            g.fillRect(theXindexcode, theYindexcode, sizeOfSquare, sizeOfSquare);
    }

    square (int theXindex, int theYindex ){
        sizeOfSquare = 10;
        theXindexcode = theXindex;
        theYindexcode = theYindex;
    }

    public void setTheColor(Color theColor) {
        this.theColor = theColor;
    }
}
```

I also have a drawing panel with this code inside it.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private final int rows = 50;
    private final int columns = 50;
    private final int pixelsize = 10;
    private final int rowIndex = 0;
    private final int colIndex = 0;
    private final boolean thisSquare = false;
    int trackX;
    int trackY;
    private boolean setColor;
    int [][] theGrid = new int[rows][columns];
    square [][] squareArray = new square[50][50];
    private int setInitialColor;
    private Color either1;

    public  DrawingPanel() {
        super();
        //thisSquare = false;
        this.addMouseListener(this);

        //Creates a random number, if that number is greater than 5, the square in the grid will be red
        //if anything else the square will be black
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 50; i2++){
                square newSquareObject = new square(i2*10, i2*10);
                squareArray[rowIndex][colIndex] = newSquareObject;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        int whatisitX = e.getX()/10*10;
        int whatisitY = e.getY()/10*10;

        trackX = whatisitX;
        trackY = whatisitY;

        System.out.println(whatisitX +","+ whatisitY);

        if(trackX>= 0 && trackX <= 500 && trackY >=0 && trackY <=500){

            System.out.println(setColor);
            setColor = true;
        }
    }

    //Create 2D array for Grid
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Loop through grid with 2D array and nested for Loop.
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= 50; rowIndex++) {

            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 50; colIndex++) {

                Random random = new Random();
                int j = random.nextInt();

                if (j >= 2) {
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                }
                else {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                }

                g.drawRect(rowIndex * 10, colIndex * 10, pixelsize, pixelsize);
                g.fillRect(rowIndex * 10, colIndex * 10, pixelsize, pixelsize);

                //Creates border for grid
                g.setColor(Color.pink);
                g.drawRect(rowIndex * 10, colIndex * 10, pixelsize, pixelsize);
            }
        }

        if (setColor == true) {

            Random random = new Random();
            Color thecolorsetter = Color.orange;

            if (random.nextInt(5) == 0){
                thecolorsetter = Color.green;

            }

            else if (random.nextInt(5) == 1){
                thecolorsetter = Color.red;
            }

            else if (random.nextInt(5) == 2){
                thecolorsetter = Color.yellow;
            }

            if (random.nextInt(5) == 3){
                thecolorsetter = Color.CYAN;
            }
            if (random.nextInt(5) == 4){
                thecolorsetter = Color.MAGENTA;
            }

            squareArray[trackX][trackY].setTheColor(thecolorsetter);
            repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public int getRowIndex() {
        return rowIndex;
    }

    public int getColIndex() {
        return colIndex;
    }
}
```

I attempted constructing the drawing panel with the rando

Comment: why don't you simple this down and make a [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that just has one square and will change color when clicked.

Comment: What is the boolean variable `setColor` supposed to do? Even if it becomes true, you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: @RoboMop It is supposed to trigger the function that switches the color the program draws in.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a one-file [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the functionality described in the question. 
 
Copy-paste the entire code into `DrawingPanel.java` and run. 
Please read the comments and do not hesitate to ask for clarifications as needed:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel{

    private static final int ROWS = 50, COLS = 50,  PIXLE_SIZE = 10,
                            GAP = 0; //change gap to 1 for example if you want to set a gap between squares

    public  DrawingPanel() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS, GAP, GAP));

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < COLS; i2++){
                Square newSquareObject = new Square(PIXLE_SIZE);
                //if random number is greater than 5, the Square in the grid will be red
                //if anything else the Square will be black
                newSquareObject.setTheColor(random.nextInt(10)>5 ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
                //you need to add each square to get it painted
                add(newSquareObject);
            }
        }

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ROWS*(PIXLE_SIZE+GAP),COLS*(PIXLE_SIZE+GAP)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args0) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new DrawingPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Square extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private final int sizeOfSquare;
    private static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Color[] colors = {Color.ORANGE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA};

    Square (int sizeOfSquare){
        this.sizeOfSquare = sizeOfSquare;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizeOfSquare , sizeOfSquare));
        setTheColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        setTheColor(colors[ new Random().nextInt(colors.length)]);
    }

    void setTheColor(Color theColor) {
        setBackground(theColor);
    }

    int getSizeOfSquare(){
        return sizeOfSquare;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```